Does privoxy have the ability to write the DOM for certain urls to disk?
I need to save the content of certain URLs which are accessed by various processes in our network. All of our network traffic passes through our Privoxy set up running on 192.168.0.1.
I added the following to my default.filter file
    ###############################################################################
# Write content of URLs containing "torob.com" to a file
###############################################################################

# Create a new log file for write.com URLs
FILTER_LOG_WRITE_URLS_FILTER write.com log-file=/path/to/write.log

# Log the content of URLs containing "write.com"
FILTER_LOG_WRITE_URLS write.com

# Let all other requests pass through untouched
FILTER_LOG_WRITE_URLS_BYPASS /

However nothing happens.
DO I have to update the actions files? or something else?
It seems that according to [---][2]

To execute external filters, Privoxy has to create temporary files.
This directive specifies the directory the temporary files should be
written to.
It should be a directory only Privoxy (and trusted users) can access.

However still the filter does not fire
Furthermore my config looks likes this:
confdir /etc/privoxy
logdir /home/services/privoxy
temporary-directory /homeservices/privoxy




actionsfile user.action
filterfile user.filter
logfile privoxy.log
 


 
toggle  1
enable-remote-toggle  0
enable-remote-http-toggle  0
enable-edit-actions 0
enforce-blocks 0
buffer-limit 4096
accept-intercepted-requests 0
split-large-forms 0
handle-as-empty-doc-returns-ok 1
logfile logfile
debug 65536 # Log the applying actions

debug  1024 # Log the destination for requests Privoxy didn't let through, and the reason why.
listen-address  0.0.0.0:21000
forward    /           .

